# Joomla Modal shows in IE (all versions) with almost empty Template

Tags: joomla, squeezebox

I am working on a template for Joomla! 2.5.4. Normally this goes very well, but today I have a weird problem.

The Joomla Modal(Squeezebox) shows in an completely empty template in all versions of IE.
[image]

The code of the template is:

```
<?php
$app            = JFactory::getApplication();
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');
?>
<?='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-en" lang="en-en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

When disabling the K2 System plugin the Modal disappears. But i need the plugin so I can't disable it.

The following is installed in Joomla:

- Joomla 2.5.4 (newest version)
- K2
- This template

The website is reachable on http://marjolein.site-project.nl

Does someone recall this problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the awnser. The XML line put the template in IE in Quirks Mode... Removing that solved it